# What is the leftost-innermost term in a lambda expression?

Tags: lambda-calculus, operator-precedence

Assume there is a lamda term like this:

[image: len (cons one nil)]

If you are reducing it by the **applicative strategy (leftmost-innermost)**, the first step is the delta reduction of `len`:

[image: (λl.l zero (λxr.succ r)) (cons one nil)]

What is the next step? Do I beta-reduce the outer lambda term?

[image: (cons one nil) zero (λxr.succ r)]

Or do I delta-reduce `zero`?

[image: (λl.l (λfa.a) (λxr.succ r)) (cons one nil)]

The latter looks right to me, because the outer lambda term is not normal and `zero` is the leftmost-innermost term of it.

Answer (score 0):

Pure lambda calculus doesn't recognize function names (in other words: all functions are anonymous), so delta-reductions are not really applicable to the process of beta-reduction and they don't influence the *evaluation* (i.e. beta-reduction) order.

In any case you don't need to delta-reduce `zero` yet, as the left-hand side of the expression can't be beta-reduced on its own - it is just more clear if you first proceed with `(cons one nil) zero (λxr.succ r)`.